# c# print function hide window

Tags: c#, printing, window

I have my main form and then launch a new form.  The new form is in the front.  I send data to the printer which opens a print window popup. (prints to default, no printer to select)  It then defaults back to my first form and I have to do a BringtoFront on the 2nd form after 1ms.  This is an ok fix because it is only a small blip, but is there a way to hide that print window popup all together so that it just prints in the background?

```
// code to print

PrintDocument prnDocument;
string printername;              //Get the default printer name.                
prnDocument = new PrintDocument();
printername = Convert.ToString(prnDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName);

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(printername))
    throw new Exception("No default printer is set.Printing failed!");               

prnDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(prnDoc_PrintPage);
prnDocument.Print();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511138/can-i-disable-the-printing-page-x-of-y-dialog), you should be able to hide the print dialog by doing the following:

```
PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
PrintController printController = new StandardPrintController();
printDocument.PrintController = printController;
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with the rest of your project.