# Make PDF by code with virtual pdf Printer in silent mode with .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf, printing

I, in my application i create the invoice printing by PrintDocument, graphics etc, using only pure code(without any reporting tool or similar)
Now i am able to print to any printer i wont but I would like to be able to change the parameters of a virtual printer by code(setting of save windows, autosave, path and file name set). I do not care if the printer is pdfcreator or bullzip or cutepdf or anything else, I'm interested in an extract of code to work on.

Thanks for your help

Salvo

Answer (score 1):

To hide the dialog please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511138/can-i-disable-the-printing-page-x-of-y-dialog)

You can use properties from [PrintDocument.PrinterSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings?view=netframework-4.7.2) to send the output to a file:

PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName

PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile

Comment: I, my problem isn't to save to a file the output, i want to create a PDF with a Virtual PDF printer, setting his value from my SW code, hiding GUI of virtual PDF printer.

Comment: Is the name of the printer known? You can select a printer with PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName

Comment: I thing my bad english not help me! When y call the printer(like bullzip or Pdf creator) appear the GUI of Virtual Printer, where user can set path for saving the PDF.I would like to set this path by code and Hide/notshow this one.